# how can get the gender and date birthday, using the facebook api?

Tags: facebook

(I am using IONIC with the plugin cordova-plugin-facebook4) With this code:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me?fields=email,name,gender,picture&access_token=' + authResponse.accessToken, ["public_profile"], function (response) {
```

I am getting this response:

```
{"email":"xxxxx@hotmail.com","name":"xxxx Molina","picture":{"data":{"height":50,"is_silhouette":false,"url":"https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=2076928542548945&height=50&width=50&ext=1539748506&hash=AeRdIrWpWFtDY_k8","width":50}},"id":"2076928542548xxx"}
```

how can get the gender and date birthday of the actual user?

Comment: did you authorize the with the correct permissions? do you actually get asked for the permissions in the login popup? are you sure a gender is selected in the profile? and why do you not ask for the birthdate in the api call?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
facebookConnectPlugin.api("<user-id>/?fields=id,email,gender,birthday",["public_profile","user_birthday"],
  function onSuccess (result) {
    console.log("Result: ", result);
    /* logs:
      {
        "id": "000000123456789",
        "email": "myemail@example.com"
      }
    */
  }, function onError (error) {
    console.error("Failed: ", error);
  }
);
```